# TypeError : "onChange is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to change parent's state value from child component but I am getting `onChange is not a function` error. I've tried all the solutions I've found but nothing helped.

This is parent component's code:

```
const [playerCount, setPlayerCount] = useState(0);
  const handleChange = (newValue) => {
    setPlayerCount(newValue);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Question question={question}/>

      {renderBoard()}

      <div className="players">
        {players}
      </div>

      <div>
        {!isBetted && allPlayersAnswered? <Bid color={playerColors[playerCount]} playerCount={playerCount} onChange={handleChange}></Bid> : ''}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

And this is `Bid.js` - child component:

```
import React from 'react'

const Bid = (color,playerCount, onChange) => {
    const handleChange = () => {
        onChange(playerCount+1);
    }
    
    return (
        <button onClick={handleChange}>Click Me</button>
    )
}

export default Bid
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Props is an object, to restructure you need to us curly brasses.  Like: const bid = ({ color, playerCount, onChange}) => {}

Comment: As an advice. Your structure is verrrrry confusing. You use 2 handleChanges that do just one operation. And `onChange` that happens actually `onClick` ....dunno...it confuses me at least :) You could `<Bid onPlayerCountChange={() => setPlayerCount(playerCount+1)}` and on `<button onClick={onPlayerCountChange}` . I guess that would work and save a bunch of time and code. And the condition could be `!isBetted && allPlayersAnswered && <Bid .... />` without ifElse. I guess your Bid component is more complex than that, otherwise just add your button in the parent component :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A component's `props` is an object so you need to pass it as such:

```
Bid = ({ color, playerCount, onChange })
```

Comment: Oh lord! I missed that ... Thank you a lot!

Comment: @kubas1178 you can tick the question to mark it as the accepted answer if it helped you

Comment: @Andy          I am also getting similar error. Trying to like this models.forEach((model) => model.onChange(handleChange));    However it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Hi @AditiSingh you should post a question. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks @Andy. I solved this problem :)